# F# bit flags enum

Tags: f#

I would like to create a bitflags enum in F#, using bitshift operators for readability: e.g.

```
[<Flags>]
type DaysOfWeek =
    | Monday = 1 <<< 0
    | Tuesday = 1 <<< 1
    | Wednesday = 1 <<< 2
    | Thursday = 1 <<< 3
    | Friday = 1 <<< 4
    | Saturday = 1 <<< 5
    | Sunday = 1 <<< 6
```

However, the F# compiler dislikes this. It says "unexpected infix operator in member definition".

I would prefer this approach over manual powers of two. Is there a way to convince the compiler that I'm not being evil?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not exactly what you asked for, but you can write the binary longhand using the `0b` prefix, eg:

```
[<Flags>]
type DaysOfWeek =
    | Monday    = 0b0000001
    | Tuesday   = 0b0000010
    | Wednesday = 0b0000100
    | Thursday  = 0b0001000
    | Friday    = 0b0010000
    | Saturday  = 0b0100000
    | Sunday    = 0b1000000
```

Comment: Good enough for me.

Answer (score 6):

Alternative way that separates the cases from the values, more verbose but more flexible:

```
type DaysOfWeek =
  | Monday
  | Tuesday
  | Wednesday
  | Thursday
  | Friday
  | Saturday
  | Sunday
  with
    static member Flag x =
      let bit n = 1 <<< n
      match x with
      | Monday ->    bit 0
      | Tuesday ->   bit 1
      | Wednesday -> bit 2
      | Thursday ->  bit 3
      | Friday ->    bit 4
      | Saturday ->  bit 5
      | Sunday ->    bit 6
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the approach recommended by Dave Fancher in *The Book of F#*

Use the Flags attribute with values that are powers of two:

```
open System

[<Flags>]    
type DayOfWeek =
  | None = 0
  | Sunday = 1
  | Monday = 2
  | Tuesday = 4
  | Wednesday = 8
  | Thursday = 16
  | Friday = 32
  | Saturday = 64
```

The Flags attribute isn't required, but makes your intention clear.

You can now represent combinations of values using the bitwise operators:

```
let weekend = DayOfWeek.Saturday ||| DayOfWeek.Sunday
```

Comment: I feel this is just a step down from marklam's answer.

Comment: So you think that binary is more legible and failsafe than integers?

What if you have a large number of items?

Comment: Exactly. It'd be hopeless having to decipher a decimal representation of even more flags. You don't even need a large number of items to demonstrate this, as additional combo flag definitions like `| Weekend = 65` and `| Workdays = 62` would be hard enough for this case. The binary representation would reveal the meaning instantly.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion, this answer doesn't use the same flag values as the question and the other answers.

Comment: Oops - I just noticed the OP explicitly preferred binary over manual powers of two. I'll leave the answer up because your comments illustrate why the accepted answer is better than the suggestion in the book. Thanks for the education.

Comment: Note that the Flags attribute actually affects how .NET treats the type. This is evident if you print out the value. If the Flags attribute is used, the string will be a list of the days that has their bits set, which is really nice. Without the Flags attribute the system will not treat combo values as such, and then just print the underlying value as decimal when no corresponding named value is found.

Comment: Hmm - I'm new to F# and that book has just fallen well down the priority list. Seems like he got this one wrong.

Comment: The website [F# for fun and profit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/) is an absolute _must read_ for newcomers to F#, and deals with the functional aspect of F# in ways you won't easily find in other books. It's free, it practically is a book, and can be downloaded. There is also a proper follow up book from the author.

Comment: I'm working through Domain Modeling Made Fuctional as you write. It's literally the best book I have ever read on Line of Business systems - and I've been hacking code since the days of punch-cards. The guy is a very clear thinker and an outstanding educator. He makes an unarguable case for the value of algebraic data types in business computing - convinced me that F# is not just a niche product for numerical work.