# F# datatypes for inclusive options

Tags: f#

I'm a C# programmer who just have found out the beauty of F# programming (thanks to the book *Domain Modeling Made Functional*). However, I surprised that I have not found examples of a common scenario: User has multiple options he can tick. For example, booking a hotel room you may want to have several extra options, like free Wifi, allergic room, pets allowed, free breakfast, free parking etc. How to model this? All the examples I have found have only two options to choose from: either opt1 or opt2, or both. That solution doesn't scale, though.

I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771463/f-bit-flags-enum/39771721), but I also need a solution for a harder case, where options may have parameter, like in the hotel room reservation example: Distance from city center (user can provide a value), Max prize per night etc. These are search options that user may tick if he wants, but if he ticks, he has to provide a required parameter for each ticked option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing as you want to have values associated with the different options, what I would do in your case would be to just use a record with multiple optional fields.

```
type Booking = 
    {
        freeWifi: unit option
        maxPricePerNight: decimal option
    }
    static member Empty =
       {
           freeWifi = None
           maxPricePerNight = None
       }
```

It may seem like extending this record would be a pain, but I don't think this would really be a case in any real life system. With things like the provided Empty member and pattern matching on individual record fields, you'd never really need to list all the fields outside the type definition.

You can see a more robust solution to this problem in CLI option parser [Argu](https://github.com/fsprojects/Argu) (using DU's and quotations to lookup option values by case name), but that's an overkill for the scenario you're handling.