# Upper and Lower Half of UInt16 in Enum?

Tags: enums, f#

I need to make an F# enum where the upper and lower bytes of the enum's value have meaning.

To make the code easily readable and maintainable in the future, I want to show each half of the uint16. Documentation refers to the number as the first 8 bits and the second 8 bits. Endianness is outside the scope of my question.

I have tried this, but it does not work.

```
type headers : uint16 =
   | firstHeader = (0 <<< 8) + (0)
   | secondHeader = (1 <<< 8) + (4)
   | thirdHeader = (2 <<< 8) + (10)
   | fourthHeader = (3 <<< 8) + (1)
```

The following works, but it obfuscates the number's meaning and introduces the possibility of calculating the composite number incorrectly.

```
type headers =
   | firstHeader = 0us
   | secondHeader = 260us
   | thirdHeader = 522us
   | fourthHeader = 769us
```

It does not need to be an enum, but I do need the same functionality (ie. being able to refer to the value as `headers.firstHeader` and get the underlying value `let x = uint16 headers.firstHeader`).

Does anyone know how to accomplish something like this?

Comment: I would answer that what you want is simply a tuple of two bytes, except I don't think you have managed to explain what it is you want to achieve and why.

Comment: Our documentation explains what they are and why it's split. The two bytes are not loosely tied together. For example, if the first byte is one, the second byte must be zero without exception. Getting into the philosophy of why it's this way and not another is not relevant to my question. I cannot find how to make an enum of tuples. Can you help me with the syntax to do that?

Comment: I am not fully convinced you'd want to use an enum, but rather some way to manipulate the two bytes in an UInt16 individually. There is a multitude of ways to do that, which makes it a bit difficult to answer your question without knowing more Normally if you want to use an enum, it's because you want to name specific literal values. If e.g. you have a need to specify values as specific bit value combinations by name, then an enum can make sense, and you can [type the individual bits in the source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771463/f-bit-flags-enum/68149679). Note the Flag attribute

Comment: @BentTranberg it is a list of constants that happen to have some outside reasoning to why they are the number they are. Storing them as tuples would be a good way to do it and I may change to that while using BrianBerns method of defining them in their own module.

Comment: If your problem simply is that you can't find a way to write an expression as in the first snippet, then I'm afraid that's the way it is in F#. To declare an enum you can use literal values, even written in hex or binary, but not expressions. Another possibility, if you want to stick with an enum type, is to use let statements to create named values from expressions, though these will not be literals.

Comment: Right, I see. Another possibility if you want to normally hide the internal representation is to use a single case discriminated union, and have functions or methods to create and extract the value (16 bit) or values (one or the other bytes).

Comment: @BentTranberg using (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/literals#integers-in-other-bases) to define them as `0x00_00us`, `0x01_04us`, etc.. is exactly what I was needing...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243726/discussion-between-uptide-and-bent-tranberg).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with an enum in F# because [enum values must be literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/enumerations). However, you could simply declare these as values within a module instead:

```ml
[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module headers =
    let firstHeader = (0 <<< 8) + (0)
    let secondHeader = (1 <<< 8) + (4)
    let thirdHeader = (2 <<< 8) + (10)
    let fourthHeader = (3 <<< 8) + (1)
```

The `RequireQualifiedAccess` attribute forces uses of the values to  explicitly refer to `headers`, just like an enum (e.g. `headers.firstHeader`).